# Warning Conflicting Types

Tags: c

I am new to C and I don't know why I would get a conflicting types error for both my scanning functions. A solution or any suggestions to improve my code would be greatly appreciated. The assignment directions are listed below.

> Your program should read in information for a file consisting of the
>   organ wait list, as well as a sequence of organs received for
>   donation. For each organ received, your program should print out the
>   name of the person and the organ they have received. The organ should
>   go to the the person who has been on the waitlist the longest, who is
>   a match for the organ. For the purposes of this assignment, a match
>   occurs when the donor organ is the same AND the bloodtype of the donor
>   is the same as the recipient. Once a match is found for an organ, they
>   should not be matched again.
>
> #### Input File Format
>
> The first line of the input file will contain a single positive integer, n (n ≤ 120000), representing the number of organs on the waiting list. The next n lines will contain information
>   about one organ each. Each of these lines will contain the person's
>   name, the organ they need replaced, their blood type, the date they
>   were added to the organ database and the time they were added to the
>   organ database. Each of these items will be separated by a space. All
>   names will be comprised of letters and underscores only, all organ
>   names will be comparised of lowercase letters, all bloodtypes will be
>   one of the previously mentioned 8 strings, all dates will be of the
>   format m/d/y, where m, d, and +y, represent the numeric month day and
>   year the patient was added to the organ donation list (for this
>   particular organ). Finally, the time will be of the form hr:min, where
>   hr(0 ≤ hr ≤ 23) and min(0 ≤ min ≤ 59) represent the numeric hour and
>   minutes for the time the patient was added to the organ donation list.
>   You are guaranteed that no two organs were added to the list on the
>   same date and time and that no name or organ name will contain more
>   than 19 characters.
>
> The following line of the input file (line number n+2), will contain a
>   single positive integer, k (k ≤ 1000) representing the number of
>   organs received, during some fixed period in time. The following k
>   lines will contain information about the organs received, in the order
>   they were received. Each of these lines will contain two strings
>   separated by a space: the name of the organ and the blood type of the
>   donor. These will both adhere to the specifications previously given.
>
> #### Output Specification
>
> Output a single line for each organ received. If a matching recipient exists in the database that hasn't yet received an organ, print out the name of the recipient, followed by
>   the organ they received. If no match exists in the database, print out
>   the following on a single line.
>
> ```
> No match found
> ```
>
> SAMPLE OUTPUT:
>
> ```
> Adam_Smith kidney
> Jessica_Arte liver
> Shelly_Zenith liver
> No match found
> No match found
> John_Lynch kidney
> ```
>
> SAMPLE INPUT:
>
> ```
> 10
> John_Lynch kidney A- 12/13/2007 14:43
> Beth_Silva lung O+ 1/23/2009 13:10
> Adam_Smith kidney A- 12/13/2007 9:59
> Jenn_Gray liver AB+ 9/9/1999 1:23
> Sylvia_Maria lung O+ 1/24/2009 0:09
> Sean_Stark heart AB- 8/23/2000 9:13
> Shelly_Zenith liver AB- 9/10/1999 1:13
> Jessica_Arte liver AB+ 8/31/1999 23:38
> Bill_Muse heart O+ 3/23/2013 3:12
> Samantha_Bogedon intestine B- 6/30/2012 17:08
> 6
> kidney A-
> liver AB+
> liver AB-
> heart O-
> intestine A+
> kidney A-
> ```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 20
#define BLOODTYPESIZE 4

//Structure to store month day and year
typedef struct {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
} dateT;
// Structure to stores hour and minute
typedef struct {
    int hour;
    int minute;
} timeT;
// structure to store name organname bloodtype dateadded time added and whether or not it was received
typedef struct {
    char name[SIZE];
    char organname[SIZE];
    char bloodtype[BLOODTYPESIZE];
    dateT dateAdded;
    timeT timeAdded;
    int received;
} organT;

int main(){
    //Declare variables
    int numberOfOrgans,x,numberOfDonors,y,match,possible;
// Create pointer to structure
organT* organ;
scanf("%d",&numberOfOrgans);
organ = (organT *)malloc(numberOfOrgans*sizeof(organT));
scanOrgans(numberOfOrgans,organ);
scanf("%d",&numberOfDonors);
organT* donors;
donors = (organT *)malloc(numberOfDonors*sizeof(organT));
scanDonors(numberOfDonors, donors);
for(y=0;y<numberOfDonors;y++){
    match=-1;
    possible=-1;
    for(x=0;x<numberOfOrgans;x++){
        if((strcmp(organ[x].organname, donors[y].organname)==0) && (strcmp(organ[x].bloodtype, donors[y].bloodtype)==0) && (organ[x].received!=1)){
           match++;
            if (match>0)
                possible=organCompare(organ, x, possible);
            else if (match==0)
                possible=x;

            }
        else continue;
    }
    if (possible>-1){
        organ[possible].received=1;
        printf("%s %s\n",organ[possible].name, organ[possible].organname);
    }
    else
        printf("No match found\n");
        free(organ);
        free(donors);
    }
}
void scanOrgans(int x,organT* organ){

    int i;
    char temp[256];

    for(i=0;i<x;i++){

        scanf("%s",&organ[i].name);
        scanf("%s",&organ[i].organname);
        scanf("%s",&organ[i].bloodtype);
        scanf("%s",&temp);
        sscanf(temp,"%d/%d/%d",&organ[i].dateAdded.month,&organ[i].dateAdded.day,&organ[i].dateAdded.year);
        scanf("%s",&temp);
        sscanf(temp,"%d:%d",&organ[i].timeAdded.hour,&organ[i].timeAdded.minute);
   }
}
void scanDonors(int x, organT* donors ){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    scanf("%s%s", &donors[i].organname, &donors[i].bloodtype);
    }
}

int organCompare(organT* organ, int x, int y){
    if (organ[x].dateAdded.year<organ[y].dateAdded.year)
        return x;
    else if(organ[x].dateAdded.year==organ[y].dateAdded.year){
        if (organ[x].dateAdded.month<organ[y].dateAdded.month)
            return x;
        else if(organ[x].dateAdded.month==organ[y].dateAdded.month){
            if (organ[x].dateAdded.day<organ[y].dateAdded.day)
            return x;
            else if (organ[x].dateAdded.day==organ[y].dateAdded.day){
                if (organ[x].timeAdded.hour<organ[y].timeAdded.hour)
                return x;
                else if (organ[x].timeAdded.hour==organ[y].timeAdded.hour){
                    if (organ[x].timeAdded.minute<organ[y].timeAdded.minute)
                    return x;
                    else return y;
                    }
                else return y;
            }
            else return y;

        }
        else return y;
        }
    else return y;

    }
```

Comment: Can you also include the exact error your compiler gave you?

Comment: Get rid of the irrelevant parts of the code and the assignment description, and add *the actual error message* instead (with all its details).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Please do _not_ tag questions with both C and C++ unless it really is about the interworking of the two languages.  In this case, since you're learning C, a C++ answer would be confusing to you — so don't tag with C++.

Comment: Also, could you include the header file? Just a hunch, but you may have the functions defined with different types in the .h file than you actually have implemented in the .c file.

Comment: Is the code snippet your code, or directly from the assignment?

Comment: Sometimes I wish people would try to pretend at least a little bit that it's not a homework problem.

Comment: See also [Segmentation Error in C Program When Run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707368/segmentation-error-in-c-program-when-run).  It's the same homework problem...though probably not the same OP.

Comment: I have used stack overflow a lot in the past for fixing errors but this has been my first time asking a question. Stackoverflow saved my butt again and I appreciate everybody who took the time to read this and provide input regarding the program and proper use of this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these three lines before `int main()`:

```
 #include <string.h>
 void scanOrgans(int x, organT* organ);  
 void scanDonors(int x, organT* donors );
 int organCompare(organT* organ, int x, int y);
```

Comment: Also, this doesn't sound right: `scanf("%s",&organ[i].name);` in `scanOrgan` function.

Comment: Thank you Schwartz, that was it.

Answer (score 2):

When using `scanf` with a `char *` you generally don't need `&`, since you already have a pointer. So change:

```
    scanf("%s",&organ[i].name);
    scanf("%s",&organ[i].organname);
    scanf("%s",&organ[i].bloodtype);
```

to:

```
    scanf("%s",organ[i].name);
    scanf("%s",organ[i].organname);
    scanf("%s",organ[i].bloodtype);
```

Also, not a bug as such, but in C you should never cast the result of malloc, so change e.g.

```
donors = (organT *)malloc(numberOfDonors*sizeof(organT));
```

to:

```
donors = malloc(numberOfDonors*sizeof(organT));
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix. As for the casting, that is how I was taught and he didn't explain why we should do it but I don't know enough to argue with him yet.

Comment: Your teacher may have been confusing C and C++ - in C++ if you use malloc then you *do* need to cast the result unfortunately (although you shouldn't normally be using malloc in C++). However in C it's not necessary, and it's also potentially dangerous as it can mask a nasty bug in some cases that the compiler would otherwise report with a warning.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't your problem, but please avoid the structure in your comparator.  Try this instead:

```
int organCompare(organT* organ, int x, int y)
{
    if (organ[x].dateAdded.year < organ[y].dateAdded.year)
        return x;
    else if (organ[x].dateAdded.year > organ[y].dateAdded.year)
        return y;
    else if (organ[x].dateAdded.month < organ[y].dateAdded.month)
        return x;
    else if (organ[x].dateAdded.month < organ[y].dateAdded.month)
        return y;
    else if (organ[x].dateAdded.day < organ[y].dateAdded.day)
        return x;
    else if (organ[x].dateAdded.day > organ[y].dateAdded.day)
        return y;
    else if (organ[x].timeAdded.hour < organ[y].timeAdded.hour)
        return x;
    else if (organ[x].timeAdded.hour > organ[y].timeAdded.hour)
        return y;
    else if (organ[x].timeAdded.minute < organ[y].timeAdded.minute)
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}
```

Comment: That looks much cleaner and simpler to understand. Thank you for the improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains because you are using functions that you haven't explicitly defined via a function prototype. I left my C reference at work, so I can't find the exact paragraph, but the compiler will guess at a functions prototype and that's causing the "conflicting types" warning or error you are seeing. From memory, C assumes functions to return an `int` if you don't specify anything.

That's my best guess. If David Schwartz's fix works, I'd be very certain that it was the cause.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what was wrong. The fix from Schwartz worked but now I know why it worked.