# Segmentation Error in C program When Run

Tags: c, arrays, search, struct, segmentation-fault

I've tried `malloc`, and no `malloc` and it will build but not run or compile. When I run the code on `codepad.org` it gives me a segmentation error. I have an array of structures I'm inputting and I'm searching through them for a specific item. That's as far as I got and no compile. The code is as follows (I used netbeans, codeblocks, and visual basic 2012 programs):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20
#define BLOODTYPESIZE 4
#define MAX 120000

typedef struct {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
} dateT;

typedef struct {
    int hour;
    int minute;
} timeT;

typedef struct {
    char name[SIZE];
    char organname[SIZE];
    char bloodtype[BLOODTYPESIZE];
    dateT dateAdded;
    timeT timeAdded;
    int received;
} organT;

int main(void) {
    int i, n, k, j;
    int c;
    int *ptr;

    char organ[SIZE];
    char bloodkind[BLOODTYPESIZE];

    organT patient[MAX];

    scanf("%d",&n);
    ptr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(*ptr));
    printf("Enter patient information\n");
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        scanf("%s", patient[i].name[SIZE]);
        scanf("%s", patient[i].organname[SIZE]);
        scanf("%s", patient[i].bloodtype[BLOODTYPESIZE]);
        scanf("%d %d %d", patient[i].dateAdded);
        scanf("%d %d", patient[i].timeAdded);
        patient[i].received = 0;
}
scanf("%d", &k);
for(j=0; j<k; j++) {
    gets(organ);
    printf("Organ received: %s", organ);
    gets(bloodkind);
    printf("Organ has blood type: %s", bloodkind);
}
for (c=0; c<n; c++){
    if(patient[i].organname == organ){
        if(patient[i].bloodtype == bloodkind){
            if(patient[i].received == 0) {
                printf("Patient(s) Found!\n");
                printf("%s", patient[i].name[SIZE]);
                printf("Organ received: %s", organ);
                patient[i].received = 1;
            }
            if(patient[i].received == 1)
                printf("Patient already received organ\n");
        }
        else("Not correct blood type\n");
    }
    else("No match found\n");
}

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Looks suspiciously similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707098/warning-conflicting-types/18707211#18707211 - is the whole class getting their homework done on StackOverflow tonight ?

Comment: Also, remove `system("pause");`, if possible.. http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html

Comment: It's just as well the macro `#define blood 8 = {A+, A-, B+, B-, AB+, AB-, O+, O-}` isn't used; it is not valid C syntax.

Comment: `for(j=1; j<=k; j++) {` indexing starts at zero in C. `for(j=0; j<k; j++) {`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are not using the address correctly.  For example, when you say

```
scanf("%s", &patient[i].name[SIZE]);
```

you are actually reading past the allocated space for `patient[i].name`.  You should change the statement to

```
scanf("%s",patient[i].name);
```

and fix other statements similarly.

Comment: thanks for the info, I think i remember hearing that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

- First check n compare to MAX
- here you access to `bloodtype[BLOODTYPESIZE]` but the last item in this tab is `bloodtype[BLOODTYPESIZE-1]`

  ```
      scanf("%s", &patient[i].bloodtype[BLOODTYPESIZE]);
  ```

The same problem is tru for other acces in the pararagraph.

Comment: Simply wrong. You try to read a string to an address the byte after `patient[i].bloodtype`.

Comment: Yes this is what I said, here you access to bloodtype[BLOODTYPESIZE] but the last item in this tab is bloodtype[BLOODTYPESIZE-1]